# 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I'm using webpack with vuejs. Webpack does its thing, but when I look at the outputted app.js file, it gives me this error.

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

I'm assuming it's a problem with babel not converting the code? Because I'm getting this in the browser when viewing the application.

> Unexpected token import

**Here's my entry.js for my vuejs application:**

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
require('./css/style.scss');

// Export the vue router
export var router = new VueRouter({
  hashbang: false,
  root: '/'
  // history: true
});

// Set up routing and match routes to components
router.map({
  '/': {
    component: require('./components/home/Home.vue')
  }
});

// Redirect to the home route if any routes are unmatched
router.redirect({
  '*': '/'
});

// Start the app on the #app div
router.start(App, '#app');
```

**Here's my webpack.config.js:**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
      filename: './public/js/app.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./public/css/style.css')
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'jshint-loader'
    }],
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
            'style',
            'css!sass'
        ),
    },
    {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/services"),
        ],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }]
  }
};
```

Here's my packages.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Myapp",
  "main": "entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server  --host $IP --port $PORT  --hot --inline --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack",
    "build": ""
  },
  "author": "Dev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.10.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^8.5.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^1.0.25",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158552/ignore-eslint-error-import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 272, accepted):

I got this error when I was missing a closing bracket.

Simplified recreation:

```
const foo = () => {
  return (
    'bar'
  );
}; <== this bracket was missing

export default foo;
```

Comment: This answer is probably the right one in 90% of cases. Check your opening closing brackets!

Comment: According to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container#issuecomment-512843419 it is fixed in "webpack": "4.36.0",

Comment: Can't believe such trivial thing would cause this much headache for me.

Answer (score 19):

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

This means that webpack is bundling the non-transpiled ES6 code, which is why these `import`/`export` statements are being found. `babel-loader` must therefore not be transpiling what you expect.

If you simply remove the `include` and `exclude` rules from its loader config, the default behavior of transpiling everything besides what's in `node_modules` will kick in. For some reason or another, the current rules are causing some/all files to be skipped.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: './public/js/app.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./public/css/style.css')
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/, 
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'jshint-loader'
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        'style',
        'css!sass'
      ),
    },
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue'
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: I have installed the babel loader and the config is as following: 
`
module.loaders = [{
  test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude : /node_modules/,
  loader  : 'babel',
  query   : {
    cacheDirectory : true,
    plugins        : ['transform-runtime', 'transform-async-to-generator'],
    presets        : ['latest', 'react', 'stage-0']
  }
}]
`
And Still it does not compile a file correctly throwing the same mentioned here error. What else might be wrong ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `latest` or `stage-0`, but have you tried adding `es2015` to `presets`?

Answer (score 13):

I got this error when I was missing a closing brace in a component method:

```
const Whoops = props => {
  const wonk = () => {props.wonk();      // <- note missing } brace!
  return (
    <View onPress={wonk} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have a .babelrc file that declares what Babel is supposed to be transpiling. I spent like 30 minutes trying to figure this exact error. After I copied a bunch of files over to a new folder and found out I didn't copy the .babelrc file because it was hidden.

```
{
  "presets": "es2015"
}
```

or something along those lines is what you are looking for inside your .babelrc file

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue using webpack4, i was missing the file .babelrc in the root folder:

```
{
    "presets":["env", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

From package.json :

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

Comment: I used similar configuration as yours, the code got compiled but in IE11 I am getting SCRIPT28 and SCRIPT2343 errors

Answer (score 6):

Using webpack 4.14.0 and babel-cli 6.26 I had to install this Babel plugin to fix the `SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` error: [babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/#installation)

It was linked through from the [Webpack Code Splitting Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).

Answer (score 5):

Look out for a double opening bracket syntax error as well `{{` which can cause this error message to appear

Answer (score 4):

I got this error after upgrading to webpack 4.29.x. It turned out that webpack 4.29.x triggered npm's [peerDependency bug](https://npm.community/t/packages-with-peerdependencies-are-incorrectly-hoisted/4794). And according to them, the bug is not going to get fixed soon. Here's the [workaround](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656#issuecomment-456713191) from [sokra](https://github.com/sokra)

- add `"acorn": "^6.0.5"` to your application package.json.
- Switch to `yarn`. It doesn't have this bug.
- `npm update acorn --depth 20` `npm dedupe` (works only in some cases)
- `rm package-lock.json` `npm i` (works only in some cases)
- update all other packages that depend on an older version for acorn (works only in some cases)
- lock webpack at `4.28.4` in your package.json

**Update**

According to comment below, this bug doesn't exist anymore after 4.36.0

Comment: According to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container#issuecomment-512843419  it is fixed in "webpack": "4.36.0"

Answer (score 2):

This is not direct answer to the original question but I hope this suggestion helps someones with similar error:

When using a newer web-api with Webpack+Babel for transpiling and you get

`Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

then you probably forgot to import a polyfill.

For example:
when using `fetch()` api and targeting for es2015, you should

1. add `whatwg-fetch` polyfill to package.json
2. add `import {fetch} from 'whatwg-fetch'`

Comment: Babel only adds polyfill for ECMAScript methods (defined at https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/).
Since `fetch` is defined by a web specification (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), you need to add the polyfill yourself.

Answer (score 1):

My error is caused by a `System.import('xxx.js')` statment. After replacing it with `import xxx from 'xxx.js'`, the error solved.

I think it is because `require('xxx.scss')` also caused a dynamic import.

For the case in the question description, in my opinion, dynamic imports is not necessary, so the problem should be solved by just replacing all `require`s with `import ... from ...`.

For some case which dynamic imports are necessary, you may need [@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/#installation) as other answers in this question.

Answer (score 1):

## Vue supports `async components`:

Source : https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/async-vuejs-components/

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ show: false }),
  components: {
    Tooltip: () => import("./Tooltip")
  }
};
</script>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

> my solution: remove **setup attribute** in your scripts tag.

In my case it was because the default `npm init vue@2^` generated my template in a way that my ***script tag*** had a ***setup attribute***. I removed the attribute an it was fixed. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Webpack 2.2.0 to bundle my React JS modules.

Encountered a similar issue while importing modules in my main app.js file.

After 30 minutes of headbanging I updated the RegEx for testing the file types in my webpack.config.js.

> Carefully notice the ? symbol in test RegEx query.

```
{
    test: /\.js?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: 'react-hot-loader'
}
```

It worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to solve this problem differently, but this is solved simply. The loader babel should be placed at the beginning of the array and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing some plugins, try:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx

npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime

npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

- If using "Webpack.config.js":

[image: Missing Plugins]

- If using ".babelrc", see answer in this [link](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/760).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by a reference to `module` in a [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/) implementation:

```js
constructor() {
  if (module && module.hot) {
    module.hot.status(status => {
      if (status === 'dispose') {
        this.webSocket.close();
      }
    });
  }
}
```