# Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level - despite putting a rule in ESLint

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, eslint, react-native-web

I am trying to turn a React Native app into a React Native Web app as well.

I want to do the following kind of import:

```
if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
    import { Route, Link, Switch, push, DeepLinking } from "react-router-native";
}
```

However I get the error:

```
Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (16:4)
```

Now I've tried to add an ESLint configuration in my package.json to prevent this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
    }
  }
```

But it is still happening.

How do I allow dynamic imports?

Comment: This is not a linting problem but literal code problem. You get a SyntaxError, after all. The error does explain exactly what's wrong - you cannot have `import` in a block, it *has* to be top level. `import`/`export` statements are designed to be statically analysable, so if you *conditionally* want to import something, that requires running logic and thus it cannot be parsed without running the application.

Comment: The dynamic form of `import("somemodule.js")` doesn't work in IE11 but it allows importing modules dynamically. It returns a Promise.

Comment: [This related question has an alternative Babel solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902849/import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level?rq=1)

Comment: @Pointy Nothing I'm changing in webpack.config.js or .babelrc seems to be changing the error message

Comment: You have to either use the native JavaScript dynamic version, *or* get Babel to do the importing at build time. In your case, I think you'll want the dynamic import because your code apparently wants to make decisions at runtime (in the browser).

Comment: @Pointy While I've done a bit of React & React Native work, I'm still learning about babel & webpack etc. What file do I put it into? How would I do the Javascript dynamic version? I've got plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"], in both my babel.config.js and my webpack.config.js (but not my .babelrc file)

Comment: The JavaScript dynamic `import` looks and works like a function call, and it returns a Promise. Thus you can use it  with `await` or a `.then()` callback.