# ReactJS - Create an Util Function in ReactJS tor reuse the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to the ReactJS framework and I have these lines of code:

```
//rest of code omitted...

const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
const dateString = `${order.data.created_at}Z`;
const localDate = new Date(dateString);
```

The other part of the code is inserted in that part of the component.
The code is working perfectly.

```
//rest of code omitted...

return (
     <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <td>{dateToTime(localDate) || emptyMessage}</td> //<-----code continuation  

//rest of code omitted...
```

I would like to do a utility function to import into various components, How do I do this?

I want to reuse the code

Answer (score 0):

Just like you export any other thing in JS.

```
// util.js
export function myFunc(params){
    // Do stuff
}


// yourComponent.js
import {myFunc} from 'path/to/util.js';

//rest of your code
// you can use myFunc(params) anywhere you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You make utils.js somewhere in your app. Then import it to your file that you want.

```
import utils from '../../utils/utils.js';
```

Use destructuring ES6

```
const { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate } = utils;
```

Then you can use it in your file

```
console.log(dateToTime);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test it now and I ´m going to return soon.

Comment: Can you explain it to me in more detail please? how would the utils body look?

Comment: same line code but in the end you use: const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate };

export default dataToExport;

Comment: I don't know which of these variables I return in the function :
const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
const dateString = `${order.data.created_at}Z`;
const localDate = new Date(dateString);

Comment: Ah you need to import the data neccesary for that 3 lines of code. If your 'order' data is only available in current js file, you need to make and import a function like the answer below, and pass the data to the variable, just like a normal function

Comment: I didi this way andit didn't work. There appears an error message: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level `code`

export function myFunc(inputDate) {
    const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
    const dateString = `${inputDate}Z`;
    const localDate = new Date(dateString);

    const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate };

    export default dataToExport
} `code`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902849/import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level